# parsing url for IIS hosted site using javascript

Tags: javascript, iis-7.5

I am hosting a web application in IIS 7.5 and need to parse the url so that that it gives the part of the url after the application name. For example if the hosted application name is `testproject` and the url entered is `http://localhost/testproject/temp/index.html` I need to extract the `/temp/index.html` part of the url. Is there any method for doing this ? I tried using javascript

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) object.

Try `window.location.pathname.replace('/testproject', '');`